# How to Customize Woocommerce/Customers page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can I customize the customers list/table that shows up in the woocommerce submenu in the admin dashboard (attached screenshot).

1- I want to change the order of columns.
2- Add some columns (based on user custom metadata).
3- Remove some columns.

These are the filters I have tried, they haven't worked for me.

'woocommerce_report_customers_export_columns'
'woocommerce_report_customers_prepare_export_item'

```
add_filter('woocommerce_report_customers_export_columns' , 'test_code');

function test_code($columns) {
    $columns['test_test'] = __( 'Test Test', 'woocommerce' );
    return $columns;
}


add_filter('woocommerce_report_customers_prepare_export_item' , 'test_code1');

function test_code1($columns) {
    $columns['test_test'] = 66;
    return $columns;
}
```

[image]